# Getting Clover POS object into webpage

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a sample inventory file in my clover and i can easily get it to my webpage in object form like this

```
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'S72P7D3J3JDCC',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Barbecue Beef',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'WNYP73ZND0T7A',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Southwest Turkey',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'EEBXBNJVGHX6E',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'The Legend (Mama\'s Club)',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '5CAE2Z0C79G2W',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Italian Mixed Meats',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'CDHQ1SC4GCMGP',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'The Brooklyn',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '87D70RM2V06JJ',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Rockstar',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 250,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'ZS4DGPN1E72RP',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Apple Juice',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 180,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'X903FNWP3DP2Y',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Orange Juice',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 200,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '3Z9PKWHB3W420',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Milk',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 200,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'XPQ0VAVNT4A4J',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Fountain Soda',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 125,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '7C2D27KKWTRRC',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Chicken Ranch Wrap',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 600,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'T0FM2007N6084',
    hidden: false,
    name: '12 Layer Grilled Cheese',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 300,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '3C719QENW2K2P',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Soup of Day',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 350,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'V6TN222KHKB1J',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Best Lil Reuben in Life',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '6TK3KY11JP3X4',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Classic BLT',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 600,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'NWR0YVE30TGA0',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Build Your Own',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 630,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'QKFBDC2V5V7GJ',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Side Salad',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 300,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'DW0YD0Y28P9ZP',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Asian Chicken Salad',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 700,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '6KSWAEA52PBSE',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Classic Chef Salad',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 730,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'ENEN22MZEQD2J',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Omelet Sandwich',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 400,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'MFFFF3K5N7KBP',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Bacon Migas',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 830,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'C88A47XXDV94T',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'PB & J Shake',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 450,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'YX16S2QWXG6TG',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Cinnamon Spice',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 320,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'WDCKQZAS0WSVA',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Seeds, Nuts & Berriers',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 320,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'RTWJKWMR6CY94',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Peanut Butter Banana',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 280,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '9Q02Y77P7FSJ0',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Two Eggs',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 125,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'PGEZKVXAFW5WE',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Two Slices of Bacon',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 150,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'P5V6X04G0QMTY',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Muffins',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 160,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'FHEAZGH5J0TV4',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Fried Potatoes',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 200,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'CS38YVQBGPBZ0',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Bagel & Cream Cheese',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 230,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '4HDRPN7T4Z2K0',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Pastrami Melt',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 410,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'X0FS9NJ08C3QT',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Breakfast Burrito',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 365,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '4MZHZ6GXRZHAR',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Ham & Cheddar Crossiant',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 420,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'G78RNR8D8ZRBE',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Hot Pastrami',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 700,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'XY61A3WN43WT2',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Pizza Panini',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 460,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'DP784MEVA71XG',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Specialty',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 450,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'RS8DJWNFQSRYC',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Nuts',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 100,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'W63Q18MH0CK3W',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Fruit',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 350,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'MBFT6Q6HPKYXT',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Savory',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 430,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '2N4TFT6SFH69T',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Plain Crepe',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 230,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '19RDCX4RG9PHR',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'California Crepe',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 450,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'PN4C4736HW7V2',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Bacon, Egg & Cheese',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 530,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'HZ183ZVH9P964',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Bananas Foster',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 350,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '0RGNBCAE5ZG4A',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Strawberries & Creme',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 350,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '7TH4J3PSYG6DY',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Lemon & Powdered Sugar',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 230,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'R8DQGDN3XV1NJ',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Everything Scramble',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 730,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'DQE8X0HDEF6PG',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Sweet Potato Scramble',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 730,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'E8QPKP8T4FP7R',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Classic Ham & Cheese Omelette',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 650,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'P7XQETG5F96TW',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Southwest Veggie Omelette',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 650,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'KJ7PBE1TFAZ4M',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Hash Browns',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 830,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'T7YBK715YYPBA',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Dutch Baby',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 700,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'F2FYJ0QK6041J',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Brown Sugar & Cinnamon',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 180,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'PR4XZWMQB50YY',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Crazy Nutty Monkey',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 415,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'F921NWSWK4ERR',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Sweet Potato Pie',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 420,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'XVSXBYJPK9W7W',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Matcha Mocha',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 530,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'G788JR7Z45SJ6',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Carrot Apple Juice',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 345,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'FWY06T2SWX9TW',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Fruit Greek Protien Shake',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 415,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'EC6QS8TD1TG1W',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'House Smoothies',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 320,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'TEN4PMP9EJZFM',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Italian Soda',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 275,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'ZA4R8MMXMMDFE',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Frank\'s Favorite Drink',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 365,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'E1H1HZRB6H5HE',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Arnold Palmer',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 220,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '26MDGG49VRAW8',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'BBQ Jerk',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 700,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '7ZPNH89XHRTVW',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'London Fog',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 230,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'E8QNTY5ETYACJ',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Chai Latte',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 415,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'VXDNBPT3TTMV4',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Tea',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 185,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'EB5FNYNCFZGT6',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Steamer',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 300,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'XQPDCC4AXM1M6',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Sicilian Panini',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 550,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'R9YHAC78EX0SG',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Candy Bar Latte Snickers',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 480,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'GE31PW6F1VF0P',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Candy Bar Latte Reeses',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 480,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: '34VND3RTN4JBC',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Candy Bar Latte Mounds',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 480,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'K687R19QTS804',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Candy Bar Latte Milky Way',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 480,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'V9TTAPT2S05V2',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Candy Bar Latte Carmello',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 480,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'FZ564D0WTCV62',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Candy Bar Latte Butter Finger',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 480,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 } ],
href:
'http://apisandbox.dev.clover.com/v3/merchants/MVEN5G1V67D21/items?limit=100' }
```

but I can not seem to get just the name value of each item.
I have tried the below code so far with no positive result

```
for(key in results) {
    if(results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = results[key];
        //do something with value;
        console.log(value)

    }
}
```

[image: returned after above code]
thats what i get after running that code so i just try to do `value.name` and get `undefined` But heres the kicker i only get undefined 2 times i dont know what is going wrong can someone please help shed some light on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each `object` to his name property. I have created a minimal example so you can see it in action:

```js
const results = [
  { id: 'S72P7D3J3JDCC',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Barbecue Beef',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'WNYP73ZND0T7A',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Southwest Turkey',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'EEBXBNJVGHX6E',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'The Legend (Mama\'s Club)',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 }
];

console.log(results.map(({name}) => name));
```

In the case there are `objects` inside the main `array` that don't have a `name` property you will get `undefined` values. So if that is your case, you can filter they out using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) after the `Array.map()`:

```
results.map(({name}) => name).filter(Boolean)
```

**Example with filter:**

```js
const results = [
  { id: 'S72P7D3J3JDCC',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Barbecue Beef',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'WNYP73ZND0T7A',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'Southwest Turkey',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'EEBXBNJVGHX6E',
    hidden: false,
    name: 'The Legend (Mama\'s Club)',
    alternateName: '',
    code: '',
    sku: '',
    price: 800,
    priceType: 'FIXED',
    defaultTaxRates: true,
    unitName: '',
    cost: 0,
    isRevenue: true,
    stockCount: 0,
    modifiedTime: 1550758062000 },
    { id: 'WNYP73ZND0T7A',
      foo: 'dummy'}
];

console.log(results.map(({name}) => name).filter(Boolean));
```